# Oracle SET DESCRIBE DEPTH is obsolete (replacement)

Tags: database, oracle

I cannot find in the Oracle docs any reference to the new version of the below command:

`SET DESCRIBE DEPTH 3
line 89: "SET DESCRIBE DEPTH 3" is Obsolete.`

How can it be achieved in newer versions of Oracle databases?

The behaviour it should mimic for Object types e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ADDRESSES AS OBJECT (
        street VARCHAR2 (25),
        house_no NUMBER(2)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PEOPLE AS OBJECT (
    name VARCHAR2 (15),
    address ADDRESSES,
    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Equals RETURN VARCHAR2,
    MEMBER FUNCTION PeopleToString RETURN VARCHAR2,
    PRAGMA RESTRICT_REFERENCES (PeopleToString, RNDS, WNDS, RNPS, WNPS)
)
NOT FINAL;

CREATE TABLE Locations (
    pseudo VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT pk_xyz_table PRIMARY KEY
    CONSTRAINT fk_loc_xyz REFERENCES XYZ(pseudo),
    person PEOPLE
);

SET DESC DEPTH 3
 DESC Locations

 PSEUDO NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)
 PEOPLE
 PEOPLE IS NOT FINAL
     NAME VARCHAR2(15)
     ADDRESS ADRESSES
         STREET VARCHAR2(25)
         HOUSE_NO NUMBER`
```

Comment: `SET DESC DEPTH n` is in [the 12c manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG074) and works fine on my SQL\*Plus.  What client are you using?  Are you using the *real* SQL\*Plus, or some other IDE's imitation?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was because of SQL Developer. I probably should have checked it in sql*plus in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET DESC DEPTH n` is not obsolete in SQL*Plus, according to the [12c manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG074) and my tests.

The problem appears to be with Oracle SQL Developer's poor imitation of SQL*Plus.  These bugs are why it's dangerous for integrated development environments to try to clone SQL*Plus.

SQL*Plus is not a great tool.  It's main advantage is it's compatibility across many platforms.  There are so many ways to "run a script", it's nice to have a method that you know will work the same for everyone.

Accept no imitation - if you need SQL*Plus, use the real thing.